# subset rows by a value while filtering columns in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, subset, rbind

I have several datasets ("001.csv","002.csv", and so on, until 332) stored in the same folder, with the following structure (example):

```
id  p1    p2    
2   35.0  na    
2   5.00  2.05  
2   0.35  1.56  
2   na    0.79 
2   5.23  0.13
2   5.01  0.03
```

I need to create a function that would read one or more files and gives me back the number of cases where both "p1" and "p2" have a given value (that is, no NA), for which I wrote this:

```
cc <- function(directory, id=1:332) {
    files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)
    for (i in id) {
            dat <- read.csv(files_list[i])
    }
    nobs <- length(which(!is.na(dat$p1) & !is.na(dat$p2)))
    completecases <- data.frame(id, nobs)
    completecases
    }
```

This works perfectly if I choose a single value for "id"; in that case, the outcome would be something like:

```
> cc(directory, 1)
    id nobs
    1  3
```

But, if I want to know the number of observations in more than one file, it gives me back, for each "id", the number of observations for the highest value of "id". For instance,

```
> cc(directory, 1:2)
    id nobs
    1  4
    2  4
```

instead of:

```
> cc(directory, 1:2)
    id nobs
    1  3
    2  4
```

I believe I need to subset my data by "id" or use "rbind" for each "id", but I have failed so far to get the right formula.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You named your function *function*? ok, R can do that, but normally this is a good idea only if you want to confuse yourself and other. `library("fortunes"); fortune(77)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it was not working is that I should include the "nobs" in the for loop, like:

```
cc <- function(directory, id=1:332) {
files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)
nobs <- c()
for (i in id) {
        dat <- read.csv(files_list[i])
        nobs <- c(nobs, length(which(!is.na(dat$p1) & !is.na(dat$p2))))
}
completecases <- data.frame(id, nobs)
completecases
}
```

Without considering it, the "nobs" as always accounting for the last value of "id" in dat.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

I edit your function to handle a single file and return the number of rows after filtering *out* rows with NA

```
count_nobs <- function(fi) {
    require(dplyr)
    dat <- read.csv(fi)
    dat[complete.cases(dat), ] %>% count()
}
```

Call the function with `purrr:map_dfr` which iterates through `files_list` and rbinds the result

```
library(tidyverse)
files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
result <- map_dfr(files_list, ~count_nobs(.x), .id="id")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fi" here?

Comment: `fi` is a local variable in the `count_nobs` environment. It takes on the value passed to it through a function call - `count_nobs(data)`. You can pass different values this way - `count_nobs(list_files[1])` or `count_nobs(list_files[2])` - but the function will know to operate on it as `fi`

Comment: Look at the simple function: `P <- function(s) { print(s) }` `P(1)` `P(2)`

Comment: When I run what you suggested, I get this error: > result <- map_dfr(files_list, ~count_nobs, .id="id")
Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : 
  Argument 1 must be a data frame or a named atomic vector, not a function

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I used your code and, although it gives me the right number of observations per ID, it provides me all of them; how can I select just few of them? And can I combine everything in a single functions?